# How can I find out what line an exception is being thrown on in Eclipse (Android)

Tags: android, eclipse, exception, line

I have a ClassCastException being thrown saying that I'm trying to cast a SeekBar as a Button but I've looked over my code 50 times and not once do I try to cast a SeekBar as a Button. How can I find out what line this apparent class mis-cast is on?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That information is available in the LogCat. See [this](http://www.appaholics.in/using-the-logcat/) link for details on how to use it.

If you are sure you are not doing such a cast, then clean the project by running `ant clean` (command line), or going to `Project -> Build -> Clean` (eclipse)

Comment: Good call; cleaning fixed the issue. I copied the XML from a different project, I suppose that was the reason. I'll mark your answer correct in 9 minutes!

Answer (score 0):

Insert a break point and simply step through until I hit the line that triggers the exception.